# Connection between multiple type of jsplumb instances

Tags: jsplumb

The two end points are created using instance.addEndpoint method but both have same instances. I need to connect between these 2 end points.

I need help for making programmatic connection between multiple types of jsplumb instances.

Comment: `multiple jsPlumb instances`, have you given it a second thought ? I can't think of any good reason to have multiple jsPlumb instances & that too which requires communicating with each other.

Comment: Its not like that. I'm creating undo operations.I've a droppable panel at the left for creating new elements. I'm keeping the connection objects in stack(Javascript Array). Upon undoing, I retrieve the connections and reconnecting it. Its working for elements that there from DOM load. I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of null" for elements created using the droppable panel. I followed the sequence of JS functions. For newly added elements, the function "jsPlumb.ConnectorEditors" in "connector-editors.js" isn't calling. Thought its taking individual instance obj.